# How to wait that ngAfterViewInit() runs while creating instance of a component from a directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I have a directive that is creating in code an instance of component template he uses and set its innerHTml, which will change the tempalte dimension:

```
  var factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponentTemplate);
  this.templateComponent = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);

  this.templateComponent.instance.htmlStr = anyText;
```

Now, here is the problem. At this stage I will get undefined on the component sizes:

```
console.log(this.templateComponent.instance.width);    //undefined
console.log(this.templateComponent.instance.height);   //undefined
```

In debug I noticed that only after my component runs **ngAfterViewInit()**, only then I can read the component template width and height from my directive and use that values.

Is there a way I can tell my directive to wait until **ngAfterViewInit()** ends,
and than do what I need from my directive with that info I'm looking for.

Comment: Why does this need to be in `ngAfterViewInit`? Why don't you just put it after `this.createComponent()`? You might need to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `cdRef.detectChanges()` first.

Comment: You absolutly right. After calling detectChanges it worked. Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of tourble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

...

  var factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponentTemplate);
  this.templateComponent = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
  this.templateComponent.instance.htmlStr = anyText;

  this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // run change detection immediately

  console.log(this.templateComponent.instance.width);    //undefined
  console.log(this.templateComponent.instance.height);   //undefined
```

Answer (score 5):

Using a globally injected `ChangeDetectorRef` isn't necessary and may not work. You can rely on the `ComponentRef`'s `changeDetectorRef` method :

```js
var factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponentTemplate);
this.templateComponent = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
this.templateComponent.instance.htmlStr = anyText;

this.templateComponent.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```